# Skip Blank Cells in a Formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am putting together a spreadsheet to assist with tracking who requires transport to an event.

On one sheet (Sheet1), the guest's name is entered (A1), then the town they need transport from (B1) which returns a "Zone" in C1, e.g. John Smith (A1) needs transport from Brighton (B1), then Brighton would return the value "Zone 1" in C1. If John Smith needs transport from Hawthorn, then it would return "Zone 2" in C1, etc.

On a separate worksheet (Sheet2), I have a summary of the five zones, and I have used an IF formula for the Name and a VLOOKUP formula for the town. So if John Smith = "Zone 1" then he appears on Sheet2 under Zone 1, if John Smith = Zone 2, then he appears under Zone 2.

For the Name formula:
=IF(Sheet1!C1="ZONE 1",Sheet1!A1,"")

For the Town formula:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$100,2,FALSE),"")

They work but when I drag the formula down, if the name "John Smith" is in Sheet1!A25, then the formula will return blank cells until Sheet2!A25, which I don't want.

What I'm trying to achieve is if Sheet1!A1 = John Smith, Sheet1!A2 = , Sheet1!A3 = Jane Smith, and both Sheet1!A1 and Sheet1!A3 = Zone 1, then they would appear on Sheet2 at A1 and A2.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your expected output. It is much easier to help you then. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: please add sample data to your question

Comment: A screenshot would be so very helpful - gotto squint with my head sideways to visualize cause I'm too lazy to recreate a3/c1/Sheet2!A25 from scratch / your question..  thanks

Comment: sounds like you're looking for filter but I simply cannot visualize what you want - highly recommend a screenshot that is synchonised/represents your situation (place both lists in single sheet separate columns if that makes it more representative / easier to screenshot in your view. ta